# Index of a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing, click

I have a set of a tags that contain the class navLink.

```
<li><a href="whatever0.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image0.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="whatever1.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="whatever2.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image2.jpg" /></a></li>
```

I have another area of the page where it contains the same number of elements (in this case 3). They are in the same order.

```
<div id="main_navi">
<ul>
<li>Some Content 0</li>
<li>Some Content 1</li>
<li>Some Content 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery plugin I'm using automatically makes everything inside #main_navi into links in a carousel type system. When you click the li tag, it scrolls to the image associated with it. I think that behavior is fine.

**Here is my issue:**
My client in their infinite wisdom wants the default behavior to change when you click on the li to take you to the page that corresponds to that image (in this case what is in the whatever.html link.

So far I did this:

```
$("#main_navi li").click(function() {
  // to find out which li was clicked on
  var index = $(this).index();

  // then i want to grab what url it was referencing..
  alert($('.naviLink').eq(index).attr('href'));
  });

});
```

**However**: when I click on the first link Some Content 0, it alerts the url for the last link (whatever2.html). What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem with adding the anchor tag to the second list?

Comment: The default behavior of the carousel just over-rides the anchor tag I put on there. There is nothing on their documentation that disables that function. (jQuery Tools)

Comment: Are you aware that your markup is invalid? A `<li>` should have `<ul>` or `<ol>` as a parent. Also `#` is not a valid character for an ID attribute.

Comment: Yes in my code I do not have the # in the div. Fixed for clarification.

Comment: @Hugo: The way your code keeps changing, I'm wondering if you created an example that is not your actual code, and didn't test it first to see if it illustrates the issue your having. Your exact code works for me. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hv4Tk/). *(I only added the parent `UL` to the first `HTML` block, and removed the trailing `});`)*

Comment: @amnotiam You are 100% correct. I did it for brevity purposes. I guess there must be something else a miss... I'll have to re-open a new entry with the whole code (jQuery Tools implementation).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the initial quote for your hrefs.

```
<li><a href="whatever0.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image0.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="whatever1.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a href="whatever2.html" class="naviLink"><img src="some-image2.jpg" /></a></li>
```

EDIt:
This should cover you.

```
$("#main_navi li").on("click", function() {
    alert($('.naviLink').eq($(this).index()).attr('href'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/dxtwy/)

Comment: Sorry in my code it is fine. Fixed to make things more clear.

Comment: Got it.  Put up a JSFiddle that should it.  Did remove the "#" the id in <div id="#main_navi"> as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$("#main_nav li").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();

$('.naviLink').each(function(index2){

if(index == index2)
{
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
}

});

});
```

Comment: try alerting index and index2 , what are the values

Answer (score 0):

It didnt work for me.My html code is

```
<input type="button"   class="buttonclose  marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
<input   type="button"   class="buttonclose  marleft fleft clrPric" value="X"> 
<input type="button"  class="buttonclose  marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
<input type="button"   class="buttonclose  marleft fleft clrPric" value="X">
```

I gave jquery like 
    $('.clrPric').click(function(){  console.log($(this).index());});

It shows only 7 in console.No other elemnts with this class.I want to get the number of the clicked button.